# People or Group field returning semicolon hash then Name

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, splistitem, query, person

In querying the properties of a list item, I found that returning the value of a *people or group* field that the value would be returned in the form

```
1;#George Grainger
```

Using the code:

```
properties.ListItem["Staff Member"].ToString();
```

I've worked around the issue, by splitting into 2 strings, but I was wondering if anyone would know of a way to return the value without the `;#` preceding the desired return value?

**Note**: I realise I could dig through the current web, list and item to query the `fieldValue.User.Name`, however this is somewhat resource expensive, and I was hoping for a "cleaner" way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below code to get User name:

```
new SPFieldLookupValue(properties.ListItem["Staff Member"].ToString()).LookupValue;
```

For User ID:

```
new SPFieldLookupValue(properties.ListItem["Staff Member"].ToString()).LookupId;
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that by using:

```
properties.ListItem["Staff Member"].ToString();
```

You are going to be returned their userID and username, so it will always be returned separated by ;#.

You're probably already using something like:

```
properties.ListItem["Staff Member"].ToString().split(";#")[1];
```

To return the username on it's own. You should compare the performance of that against `fieldValue.User.Name` and see which is less taxing.

There might be another field value I am missing that you could use in it's place, but I have always just split their ID from the name.

Comment: This was the workaround that I was alluding to in my question, I was hoping for the "proper" way to do it